# Taylor Series Clarification

Tags: taylor-expansion

For $\sin(x)$, $e^x$, $\cos(x)$... When we are building the $n$-th taylor polynomial, why is it that we always evaluate the functions first $k$ derivatives at $x=0$? In my textbook when they were deriving the formula for each of those 3 functions, they would always evaluate all the derivatives at $x=0$ but why not at some other value of $x$ that is more general?

Comment: Because one is Maclaurin ($x=0$) and the other is Taylor (general) but the later contains the former.

Comment: You can find it at a different point, for instance $e^{x}$ has the Taylor series at $x=a$ $$e^x = e^a \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x-a)^k}{k!} .$$

Comment: For a lot of series (like $e^{x}$) the $a=0$ choice is convenient because you actually know what that value is.  For example, in science's comment above, if you pick a value other than $a=0$ how do you evaluate the $e^{a}$ term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three answers to this question:

1. For the functions you list, you don't gain a lot by expanding about another point, because you have identities like
   $$ e^x = e^{a+(x-a)} = e^a e^{x-a}, $$
   so the Taylor series of $e^x$ about the point $x=a$ is
   $$ e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^a \frac{(x-a)^k}{k!}, $$
   which has much the same properties as the Taylor series of $e^x$. You can do the same thing with $\sin{x}$ and $\cos{x}$ using the addition formulae like
   $$ \sin{(a+(x-a))} = \sin{a}\cos{(x-a)} + \cos{a} \sin{(x-a)}, $$
   and you know how to expand those about $x=a$ from your results at $0$.
2. More generally, it *is* often useful to expand about a point other than $x=0$. A classic example is the logarithm: $\log{x}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, but at $x=1$ we do have an expansion, which you may not have noticed because we often write it a different way:
   $$ \log{(1+x)} = x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\dotsb $$
3. The most general answer is that the Maclaurin series of the function is the Taylor series of the translate of a function ($f(x-a)$, basically). Often, when looking at a finite number of terms, it's just easier to deal with a polynomial in $x$

And sometimes, expansions about different points can look quite different. Consider the following series:
$$ 1-x^2+x^4-\dotsb = \frac{1}{1+x^2} \quad (|x|<1) \tag{1} $$
Now consider this series:
$$ \tfrac{1}{2}-\tfrac{1}{2}x+\tfrac{1}{4}x^2-\tfrac{1}{8}x^4+\tfrac{1}{8}x^5-\dotsb. \tag{2} $$
What you don't know about this series is that it's actually the Taylor series of
$$ \frac{1}{1+(1+x)^2}, $$
about $x=0$, so it's also the Taylor series of $(1+x^2)^{-1}$ about $x=1$. (2) looks a lot worse than (1) (you and I would struggle to guess what (2)'s $n$th term is, for one thing), but (using techniques you learn in Analysis courses at university), you can show that (2) actually converges for $|x-1|<\sqrt{2}$, so in a sense it's more useful, because it covers a larger range of possible $x$ values.

Therefore I'd say the normal reason people would give when asked is that *there are just some points for which the series is easier to calculate, and this series works for the values of $x$ we're interested in, which is good enough*. (In the case of the exponential and sine and cosine, all values of $x$, in fact.)